# System ui crashing after installing cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, android-versions

This is my first time installing a custom image, so I am really just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

I have a moto x developer edition 2013 that I installed cyanogenmod 12.1 on. However, after its been running for a few minutes, I will get a error that the system ui crashed. It then goes into a loop of crashing.

I tried installing cyanogenmod 11 with the same results. I gave tried wiping the cache (which is the suggestion I see elsewhere about issues like this).

I must have done something wrong if this is happening on two different versions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the data of the SystemUI application from the Settings->Apps-All Apps menu.

If you cannot operate the phone because the crashes are too frequent, you can do it with a computer through ADB shell command.